# Do I need to convert this Array in Objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

My `data` is an array that I'm converting into a `key:value` (not sure if this is what it's called) type.

**Data:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Name 01",
        "tags": [
            "TAG1",
            "TAG4",
            "TAG2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Name 02",
        "tags": [
            "TAG4",
            "TAG3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Name 03",
        "tags": [
            "TAG1"
        ]
    }
]
```

I'm converting this into :

```
result = data.map(a => ({ [a.id]: a }));
```

So I'm getting:

**Result:**

```
[
    {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Post1 T1 T2 T4",
            "tags": [
                "TAG1",
                "TAG4",
                "TAG2"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "2": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Post1 T3 T4",
            "tags": [
                "TAG4",
                "TAG3"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "3": {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Post3 with No Tags",
            "tags": [
                "TAG1"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

How can I map the results and show in a `View/Text`?

I tried:

```
Object.keys(results).map((result, idx) => {
  return(
      <View key={idx}>
        <Text>{result.title}</Text>
      </View>
    )
});
```

But I'm getting an error : `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.`

Do I need to convert the results to an object and only then I'll be able to use `Object.keys`. If yes, how do I convert the entire result in an Object like this:

Results:

```
{
    {
        "1": {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Post1 T1 T2 T4",
            "tags": [
                "TAG1",
                "TAG4",
                "TAG2"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "2": {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Post1 T3 T4",
            "tags": [
                "TAG4",
                "TAG3"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "3": {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Post3 with No Tags",
            "tags": [
                "TAG1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The reason I'm doing this is to target the id for a reducer dispatched action:

```
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INC_NUM":
         const newState = {...state};
         newState[action.payload].nubmer++;
         return newState;
```

Comment: er, uhm. why? all you're doing is wrapping each inner object with another object, what goal does that serve? All it does is force you to refer to the object with `theArray[0][1].id` rather than `theArray[0].id`. it literally does nothing productive.

Comment: Is that why you downvoted my question? I updated it. The current `data/result` don't have the `number` key in there. But I'm trying to get this sorted first. How would you propose to target the array of these objects with the `id` of an object if it's not defined outside the array?

Comment: it inherently does, because arrays are indexed starting with 0. So id1 is 0, id2 is 1, etc. Assuming you don't have any missing id's, this should continue linearly. You could however convert the array into an object that follows a similar structure where the key is the id.

Comment: Thats what I did in the **Result** that I'm showing the first time. But I am not able to show it with `map`. That is the initial question of this post. Please help.

Comment: no, the result you have is still an array.

Comment: .map always returns an array, so if you want something else you'll have to do something else.

Comment: That's what I wanted to change. `Results` is an array. I am happy to use `Object.keys` on `Results` id it's an `Object`. But even that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just want to be able to quickly find the object that has a given id value.  Rather than "convert" your data, I'd suggest you just make a map so you can look up any object by id.

```js
let data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Name 01",
        "tags": [
            "TAG1",
            "TAG4",
            "TAG2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Name 02",
        "tags": [
            "TAG4",
            "TAG3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "title": "Name 03",
        "tags": [
            "TAG1"
        ]
    }
];

// create a map with id as the key, object as the value
let map = new Map();
data.forEach(obj => {
   map.set(obj.id, obj);
});

// look up a given id
console.log(map.get(3));
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  Please tell me what is wrong with this answer so I can correct or improve it.  Downvotes without any reason are really not very helpful to the community.

Comment: Even my question is downvoted and I still don;t understand why. I asked a question and instead of explaining they just downvote it. Not cool. They're making it difficult for a beginner to learn.

Comment: @Somename - Your question is likely downvoted because it is not very clear.  The very first thing you need to do in your question is explain the actual problem you're trying to solve.  Show exactly what output you want or what code you're trying to make work.  You spend a lot of energy documenting all the code you've tried, but very little explaining what the root problem is that you're trying to solve.  I had to GUESS that this is what you wanted because your question is NOT very clear.  This site **requires** you to write clear questions which lots of people are bad at.

Comment: @Somename - And, while we're at it, does this answer solve your problem or not?  If not, please explain why and then go clarify your question.

Comment: Your answer actually solves this. It's exactly what I'm looking for. Im trying to figure out how to handle the action in the reducer now. Thanks.